# Not to print header information when using summary(mcmc) in coda package

Tags: summary, mcmc, coda

I have wrote a function that extracts already-thinned and post-warmup MCMC samples after some processing, and the output is a mcmc object. However when I run the summary() function, it naturally does not recognize that the output is already processed, hence display incorrect information in the header, i.e. Iterations etc.

My question is, is there a way to not display the header information when I call summary(mcmc object)?

```html
> summary(output)

Iterations = 1:10000
Thinning interval = 1 
Number of chains = 1 
Sample size per chain = 10000

1. Empirical mean and standard deviation for each variable,
   plus standard error of the mean:

           Mean        SD  Naive SE Time-series SE
beta  1.052e+00 3.189e-02 8.914e-04      9.185e-04
df    3.849e+00 2.916e-01 8.150e-03      1.516e-02
sigma 1.056e-02 2.504e-04 6.998e-06      1.000e-05
tau   8.990e+03 4.273e+02 1.194e+01      1.710e+01

2. Quantiles for each variable:

           2.5%       25%       50%       75%     97.5%
beta  9.891e-01 1.032e+00 1.052e+00 1.073e+00 1.113e+00
df    3.304e+00 3.650e+00 3.836e+00 4.042e+00 4.450e+00
sigma 1.004e-02 1.039e-02 1.055e-02 1.072e-02 1.105e-02
tau   8.197e+03 8.700e+03 8.977e+03 9.263e+03 9.917e+03
```